# creating Azure Data factory linked service using Managed identity with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using python scripts to create and manage data factory pipelines, when I want to create a linked service, I'm just using this code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python#create-a-linked-service

but now I want to create the linked service using managed identity and not by name and key, and I can't find any example of how to do it with python.

I managed to do it manually like so:
[image]

but I want to do it using python.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> service_endpoint str  Required  Blob service endpoint of the Azure
> Blob Storage resource. It is mutually exclusive with connectionString,
> sasUri property.

According to the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models.azureblobstoragelinkedservice?view=azure-python), you should use `service_endpoint` to create linked service with Managed identity. You should pass Blob service endpoint to `service_endpoint`.

The following is my test code:

```
ls_name = 'storageLinkedService001'
endpoint_string = 'https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net'
ls_azure_storage = LinkedServiceResource(properties=AzureBlobStorageLinkedService(service_endpoint=endpoint_string))
ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: you are my hero :)